# Copying from sheets and leaving blank rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I got 2 sheets and on the first on I got the dates. And I'd need to copy the dates but leave 2 blank row under the certain date(If possible then the 3 rows should be merged)

For example: [1st sheet](http://prnt.sc/ekd02n), [2nd sheet](http://prnt.sc/ekd08t)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Formular for column `A`. Paste it down as long you need.

```
=IF((ROW()/3)=(INT(ROW()/3)),INDIRECT("<Sheet1>!A"&ROW()/3),"")
```

Merge cells is normally a bad idea. Think twice if you really want it. This merging of cells can only be done in VBA.